# How do I connect two ActionListeners and let them return something

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I have to create a crossword puzzle for an assignment. The crossword consists of buttons and when you click on one, a keyboard should appear. If you select a letter, the first button should shown this letter on the GUI.

Below is a class called Puzzle which displays two buttons on the screen without any text. Clicking on one of the buttons starts the Keyboard class. Which presents a Keyboard as a GUI and on choosing for example the letter 'A', the first button would now have the letter 'A' as text. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Puzzle extends JPanel {
    public Puzzle(ActionListener listener) {
        JFrame f =new JFrame("Button Example");
        JButton a =new JButton();
        JButton b = new JButton();
        a.setBounds(50,100,95,30);
        b.setBounds(50,300,95,30);
        f.add(a);
        f.add(b);
        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        a.addActionListener(listener);
        b.addActionListener(listener);
        //do other stuff
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Puzzle w = new Puzzle(new Keyboard());
        //continue with initialization process
    }
}
```

The second class Keyboard that has to work with it.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Keyboard implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // needs to create Keyboard en return letter to Puzzle
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: The `actionPerformed` method cannot return a value.  However, the `Keyboard` class can hold and return a `char` or `String` value.

Comment: Your GUI design will be aggravating for a user.  Pop up a [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) and let the user type in the whole word at once.

Comment: Is it possible to modify JOptionPane to have 26 buttons, each with a letter of the alphabet in it?

Comment: _Is it possible to modify JOptionPane to have 26 buttons, each with a letter of the alphabet in it?_ Yes it is. Refer to [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) which is part of Oracle's Java tutorials.